# Counting number of elements that fall between two values in each column of sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix, such as below

```
library(Matrix)

set.seed(2019)
nrows <- 10L
ncols <- 5L
vals <- sample(
  x = c(0,1,2,3),
  prob = c(0.7,0.1,0.1,0.1),
  size = nrows*ncols,
  replace = TRUE
)
mat <- matrix(vals,nrow=nrows)
matSparse <- as(mat,"sparseMatrix")

> matSparse
10 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] 2 2 . . .
 [2,] 2 . . . .
 [3,] . . 1 3 3
 [4,] . . . . .
 [5,] . . . . 3
 [6,] . . . . .
 [7,] 3 . . . 1
 [8,] . 2 1 . 1
 [9,] . . . . .
[10,] . . . 2 .
```

I'd like to compute for each column the number of elements that fall between certain values (may be different for each column). For example, I have a vector (of length `ncols`)  `brks = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2)`. I would like to compute for each column `j` the following things:

1) The number of elements that are `> 0(.)` and `<=brks[j]`
2) The number of elements that are `>brks[j]`.

In the above example, the result would be 1) `0 2 2 1 2` and 2) `3 0 0 1 2`.

I've tried creating logical sparse matrices of class `lgeMatrix` and applying `colSums`, but have been unsuccessful. In the end I'd like to have an *efficient* way of doing this as I have very large matrices (`10000` rows and `100000` columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you compared against a matrix of the same dimensions?

```
cmpr <- t(brks)[rep(1,nrow(matSparse)),]

colSums(matSparse > 0 & matSparse <= cmpr)
#[1] 0 2 2 1 2

colSums(matSparse > cmpr)
#[1] 3 0 0 1 2
```

Or even `sweep`:

```
gt0ltB <- function(x,y) x > 0 & x <= y
gtB    <- function(x,y) x > y

colSums(sweep(matSparse, STATS=brks, MARGIN=2, FUN=gt0ltB))
#[1] 0 2 2 1 2
colSums(sweep(matSparse, STATS=brks, MARGIN=2, FUN=gtB))
#[1] 3 0 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to iterate over each column and `brks`

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(matSparse)), function(i) 
                sum(matSparse[, i] > 0 & matSparse[, i] <= brks[i]))
#[1] 0 2 2 1 2

sapply(seq_len(ncol(matSparse)), function(i) sum(matSparse[, i] > brks[i]))
#[1] 3 0 0 1 2
```

Since in both the conditions we are looping over columns, we can also combine the two conditions and do it one `sapply` call

```
t(sapply(seq_len(ncol(matSparse)), function(i) 
       c(sum(matSparse[, i] > 0 & matSparse[, i] <= brks[i]), 
         sum(matSparse[, i] > brks[i]))))

#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    3
#[2,]    2    0
#[3,]    2    0
#[4,]    1    1
#[5,]    2    2
```

where 1st column is output of 1st condition and 2nd for 2nd condition.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post right before you posted your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered loops and the `apply` family of functions, but that is too slow for my application. I'm trying to leverage the sparse nature of the dataset.